# What happened to the POIs-module in OSMnx - and what to use now?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I want to extract data from OSM, similar to this blogpost:
https://blogs.sap.com/2020/01/20/where-to-not-charge-my-car-openstreetmap-pois-in-sap-hana/

One of the first examples is:

`gdf_poi = ox.pois_from_place('Germany', amenities=['charging_station'])`

But this leads to: `AttributeError: module 'osmnx' has no attribute 'pois_from_place'`

Searching in the code I find this line in the changelog from version 0.16.2 to 1.0.0: `- remove deprecated pois module`

So - does anyone has an example on how to e.g. get a list of all nodes with amenity "charging_station" in Germany?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this was deprecated a while back and eventually removed. The `geometries` module replaced it and offers this functionality. See the documentation https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.geometries

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not find it bc I focussed on "poi" and the old method names as search term - maybe you can add a "This method can be used instead of poi.[xxx]" in the manual?